# Prime Number Test in java

Tags: java

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number)
{
  boolean result = true;

  for (int i=2; i < number/2; i++)
  {
     if (number%i == 0)
     {
        result = false;
     }
  }

  return result;
}
```

This code works but how can I modify it such that when int number = 0, it returns as false? Currently when number = 0, it returns as true.

Comment: Do exactly what you just described.

Comment: I think 1 isn´t prime too, per definition

Comment: Incidentally - you only need to loop to `sqrt(number)` rather than `number/2` and you can loop in increments of 2 also.

Comment: Though that's not a really efficient way to check for prime numbers. Google for 'eratosthenes sieve' for a nicer one ;)

Comment: @BoristheSpider If he increments by 2, then the number 9 will be prime.

Comment: @NicolasDefranoux the sieve is good for finding _all_ the primes within a range - this method checks if a single number is prime. I think for this method is better in this case.

Comment: @mikeyaworski - after checking 2, you start with 3 and then you can iterate through odd numbers only (thus incrementing +2)

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Sure, but the sieve articles gives good ideas of optimizations. Trying only odd numbers is a first step, but then why trying multiples of 3 (they are super easy to bypass), etc.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Then every number would be composite if he started at 1. And then 8 would be prime if it only tested odd numbers.

Comment: @libik Yes, that is the correct way to implement that strategy.

Comment: @mikeyaworski you're absolutely right - I'm having a bit of a brainfart. See libik's comment about checking 2 then starting from 3.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is really as easy as it looks like :)

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    boolean result = true;
    if (number == 0){
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < number / 2; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            result = false;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Effective way how to do this method is :

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    //Everything less or equal 1 is not prime number
    if (number <= 1) {
        return false;
    }

    //2 is very special case, so I check it separately
    if (number == 2) {
        return true;
    }

    //This will help me rid off all even numbers
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }


    //It is important to count the sqrt before using it in for-loop condition.
    //If you use it in for-loop condition, it will be counted every single iteration.
    int square = (int) Math.sqrt(number);

    //I already checked %2, so now I need to check only odd numbers
    for (int i = 3; i <= square; i += 2) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            //If I find one number, I do not have to continue
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In this case your loop will evaluate only `number = number % (number /2)` as all previous will be override.

Comment: @Vash - I do not understand what you want to say :). What exactly will be overriden?

Comment: I mean that you do not have to run to the end. you can put return in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {

    if (number < 2){
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < number / 2; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```